# Java Swing : Graphic component only appears in top-left corner zone

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, display

I am currently trying to realise a simple animation in Java.
I have one panel in which I would like to print one BufferedImage. I set the image location at one point and I set its dimensions.

However it is as if I was placing the "print zone" of my image in the top-left with its dimensions, and only the part of my image that belongs to that print zone is drawn as you can see on the folowing picture :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRmCv.png]

I guess it is propably one basic stuff I am missing however I cannot find any answer corresponding to my problem and I am a beginer in java so..

Here is the part of my code that is related to this problem :

```
public abstract class ObjetAnime extends JPanel{
protected Point location;
protected Dimension dim;
protected BufferedImage picture;

ObjetAnime(ObjetsPropriete objetProp) 
{
    location = new Point(10,10);
    dim = objetProp.getDimension();
    try {
        picture = ImageIO.read(new File(objetProp.getPath()));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.setSize(dim);
    this.setLocation(location);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setOpaque(false);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

  if (picture != null) {
     g.drawImage(picture, location.x, location.y, this);
  }
}
```

And in the super class I have :

```
public ListeObjets(GConfig gconfig, GPanel jeuPanel)
{
    setListeObjets(new ArrayList<ObjetAnime>());
    panel = jeuPanel;
    for( int i = 0; i < gconfig.getObjetsTab().length; ++i)
    {
        switch(gconfig.getObjetsTab()[i].getType())
        {
            case ROND:
                getListeObjets().add(new Rond(gconfig.getObjetsTab()[i]));
            break;
        }
    }
    addToPanel(panel);
}

public void addToPanel(GPanel jeuPanel) {
    jeuPanel.setLayout(null);
    Iterator iterator = getListeObjets().iterator();
    ObjetAnime obj = (ObjetAnime) iterator.next();
    jeuPanel.add(obj, obj.location);
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        obj = (ObjetAnime) iterator.next();
        jeuPanel.add(obj, obj.location);
    }   
    System.out.println(obj);

}
```

And the object properties are :

```
public ObjetsPropriete()
{
    path = new String("./Images/Boule.png");
    dim = new Dimension(32,32);
    type = Objet.ROND;
}
```

Thanks a lot and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you answer, thanks to this I've found out how to solve my problem.

The cause of the problem was the use drawImage at the objectLocation while drawImage print on the object itself at the specified location.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

  if (picture != null) {
     g.drawImage(picture, 0, 0, this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
location = new Point(10,10);
```

All your objects have a location of (10, 10), so I would guess they point over top of one another. So get rid of that statement.

```
jeuPanel.add(obj, obj.location);
```

The second parameter means nothing to the add(...) method. It does not specify the location of the component. Get rid of the second parameter.

(if I understand your code) and you want to specify the location then you need to do something like:

```
//getListeObjets().add(new Rond(gconfig.getObjetsTab()[i]));
Rond rond = new Rond(gconfig.getObjetsTab()[i]);
rond.setLocation(32*i, 32*i);
getListeObjets().add(rond);
```

The above code would position each object diagonally in the panel.

The key point is you need to set each component to a unique location.